# Invertibility of vector valued functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be defined by $$f(x)=x||x||^2$$then is $f$ invertible?

For $n=1,~f$ is invertible since  $x|x|^2=x^3$ is both one-one and on-to...how can we deal with $n> 1$?

Comment: If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x\|x\|^2=y\|y\|^2$. Therefore $x$ and $y$ and collinear. Write $y=rx$, for some real $r$. Then $x\|x\|^2=r^3x\|x\|^2$. So, either $x=y=0$ or $r^3=1$, which implies that $r=1$, i.e. $x=y$.

Comment: @logarithm Why not post that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same idea works to find the inverse $f^{-1}(x)$.  Note that it has to be on the same ray $0x$.  So on this ray $f(tx), t\in\mathbb{R}$, it just reduce to solving the parameter $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$, which is the same equation.  The end result is
$$
f^{-1}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x=0\\
\dfrac{x}{\lVert x\rVert^{2/3}} & x\neq 0
\end{cases}.
$$